# Database relationship - sandwhich ingredients for a menu in Access

Tags: database, ms-access-2007, relationship, database-schema

I have a database design question.  I have been asked to do a simple menu application in Access 2007 for a little restaurant.  I have done applications in 2007 before, have familiarity with VBA but I am trying to think of the most efficient way to design this.

The restaurant has a number of raw ingredients - Vegetables (multiple types), Meats (multiple types), Sauces (multiple types), etc.  A combination of these would make a Sandwich or a salad (other associations exist but for my question lets stick to these two).  And each ingredient is measured with a gross cost and customer cost per serving.  Say 100 grams of ham is one "serving" - 10 grams of lettuce - one "serving".

So a "sandwich" can have multiple types of meat, multiple types of vegetables, multiple types of sauces.  At first I was thinking of a "Meat" table, "Vegetables" table, "sauce" table, all with many to many relationships to a  "Sandwich" table which is an association table that sits between all three.

So the sandwich table would have
ID, MeatID, VegID, SauceID, Name, GrossPrice (calculated from the other three tables), CustPrice (calculated from the other 3 tables), etc.

But that got me thinking that a given sandwich *will* have several vegetables, meats, and sauces potentially.  So an "Ultimate" sandwich will have Ham, Beef, Onion, Lettuce, Pickles, Mayonnaise, Vinegar lets say.  2 meats, 3 veggies, and 2 sauces.  That's not going to work for a simple association table.  This also doesn't include things like "double meat" or salads which would have lettuce x 5.

Obviously I'm not a full on DBA - I putter with this and it is not my primary job by any means.  How would you design a table schema for this?  Simple but complex when you think about it.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a table structure like below. I have used an example of Sandwich however you can have a single table for both sandwich or Salad with a Type attribute which distinguishes whether its a Salad or a Sandwich.

```
Table - Ingredient
------------------
IngredientID (PK)
IngredientName
IngredientType (Vegetables,Meat,Sauce)
SingleServingCost

Table - Sandwich
------------------
SandwichID (PK)
SandwichName
GrossCost
CustPrice

Table - SandwichIngredient
------------------
SandwichIngredientID (PK)
SandwichID (FK to Sandwich)
IngredientID (FK to Ingredient)
TotalServings (If a sandwich can have multiple servings of a single ingredients)
```